# FD_ISSET return 0

Tags: c, windows, networking

I've seen a similar post here, but I still can't figure out the answer.
I’m trying to do this receiving function in C on Windows:

```
void receiving(int server_fd){
struct sockaddr_in address;
int valread;
char buffer[2000] = {0};
int addrlen = sizeof(address);
fd_set current_sockets, ready_sockets;

//Initialize my current set
FD_ZERO(&current_sockets);
FD_SET(server_fd, &current_sockets);
int k = 0;
while (1)
{
    k++;
    ready_sockets = current_sockets;

    if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &ready_sockets, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &ready_sockets))
        {

            if (i == server_fd)
            {
                int client_socket;

                if ((client_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t *)&addrlen)) < 0)
                {
                    perror("accept");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                FD_SET(client_socket, &current_sockets);
            }
            else
            {
                valread = recv(i, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                printf("IP address recv2 is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr));
                printf("\n%s\n", buffer);
                FD_CLR(i, &current_sockets);
            }
        }
    }

    if (k == (FD_SETSIZE * 2))
        break;
}
```

}

Unfortunately, the program doesn’t enter in the if(FD_ISSET(i,&ready_socket)). FD_ISSET always returns 0.
Does anyone know why ?
Thanks

Comment: What was the return value of `select()`. Zero?

Comment: As far as I know, `FD_SETSIZE` has a different meaning in Windows (compared to the meaning in Linux): While the `fd_set` is a bit mask of file handles in Linux, it is an array of `SOCKET` handles in Windows. For this reason, an `fd_set` can contain at most `FD_SETSIZE` entries but the value of each entry (`server_fd` in your case) may be larger than `FD_SETSIZE`. Did you already check if `FD_SETSIZE > server_fd`?

Comment: @user207421 The `select()` returns 1

Comment: @MartinRosenau Actually, `FD_SETSIZE` was smaller than `server_fd`. I changed the value of `FD_SETSIZE` at the beginning with `#ifndef FD_SETSIZE #define FD_SETSIZE 1024 #endif`. Now, the problem is solved. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CobraNo56 This is not a good idea: This will increase the size of `fd_set` to 1024 entries so the memory needed will be huge. And it will not really solve your problem: After the next Windows update, `socket()` may return 12345 which is more than 1024. Under Windows, you cannot use the `for(... i<FD_SETSIZE ...)` loop in this way but you will have to create some array that contains all sockets in use by your program and to do something like this: `for(i=0; i<num_open_sockets; i++) if(FD_ISSET(my_open_sockets[i], ...)) ... `